# VueJS Не отрисовывается график

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Вообщем есть страница которая выглядит примерно так:

```
<v-row>
    <v-col cols="12" md="6" sm="12" :class="{'nonVisible': !income }">
      <v-card elevation="2" outlined>
        <v-card-title>
          <h4 class="title">{{ $t('history.chart.income') }}</h4>
        </v-card-title>
        <div>
          <chart :data="chart_1"></chart>
        </div>
      </v-card>
    </v-col>

    <v-col cols="12" md="6" sm="12" :class="{'nonVisible': !outcome }">
      <v-card elevation="2" outlined>
        <v-card-title>
          <h4 class="title">{{ $t('history.chart.outcome') }}</h4>
        </v-card-title>
        <div>
          <chart :data="chart_2"></chart>
        </div>
      </v-card>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
```

Есть методы:

```
...
chart_1: {
  labels: 'Default',
  datasets: [{ label: 'Default', backgroundColor: '#fff', data: [100] }]
},
chart_2: {
  labels: 'Default',
  datasets: [{ label: 'Default', backgroundColor: '#fff', data: [100] }]
},
...
getCharts () {
  this.$store.dispatch('getAllEvents', '').then(() => {
    this.setChart_1();
    this.setChart_2();
  }).catch(() => {})
},
setChart_1 () {
  let labels_chart_1 = []
  const colors_chart_1 = []
  const dats_chart_1 = []

  if (this.$store.getters.income !== null) {
    this.$store.getters.income.forEach((income) => {
      let normalIncome = JSON.parse(income)

      labels_chart_1.push(this.$i18n.t(normalIncome.label))
      colors_chart_1.push(normalIncome.color)
      dats_chart_1.push(parseFloat(normalIncome.total.toFixed(2)))
    })
  }

  this.chart_1 = {
    labels: labels_chart_1,
    datasets: [{ label: this.$i18n.t('history.chart.income'), backgroundColor: colors_chart_1, data: dats_chart_1 }]
  }
},
setChart_2 () {
  let labels_chart_2 = []
  const colors_chart_2 = []
  const dats_chart_2 = []

  if (this.$store.getters.outcome !== null) {
    this.$store.getters.outcome.forEach((outcome) => {
      let normalOutcome = JSON.parse(outcome)

      labels_chart_2.push(this.$i18n.t(normalOutcome.label))
      colors_chart_2.push(normalOutcome.color)
      dats_chart_2.push(parseFloat(normalOutcome.total.toFixed(2)))
    })
  }

  this.chart_2 = {
    labels: labels_chart_2,
    datasets: [{ label: this.$i18n.t('history.chart.outcome'), backgroundColor: colors_chart_2, data: dats_chart_2 }]
  }
},
```

Проблема такая, сейчас я переписал, что бы компонент был display:none до этого он скрывался через v-if и пол умолчанию его данные были вообще null. Когда приходят нужные данные они вставляются всё появляется кроме графиков они пустые, повторно вызываю метод, графики отрисовываются. Нужна помощь, не могу понять, почему они не показываются с первого раза.

Графики рисую с помощью vue-chartjs.

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем я нашел ответ на свой вопрос, он как обычно был в документации, которую я читал 1000 лет назад, вообщем в графики данные передаю во ттак:

```
<div>
    <chart :chart-data="chart_1"></chart>
</div>
...
<div>
    <chart :chart-data="chart_2"></chart>
</div>
```

А в сам компонент графика добавляется миксин, но общий код выглядит так:

```
<script>
  import { Doughnut, mixins } from 'vue-chartjs'
  const { reactiveProp } = mixins

  export default {
    extends: Doughnut,
    mixins: [reactiveProp],
    props: ['chartData'],
    mounted () {
      this.renderChart(this.chartData, { responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false })
  }
}
</script>
```